# html5boilerplate site for both desktop and mobile browsers

Tags: mobile, cross-browser, html5boilerplate

I've created a very simple site which has a nav bar and a set of static pages.  I did this using html5boilerplate as a starting point and then added my pages in.  It looks great on desktop browsers!

I now would like the same site to also look good on mobile devices.  I ran across the html5boilerplate/mobile version.  So I'm wondering, is the expectation that you create a completely separate site for mobile?

I was wondering if there were just CSS tricks you could do to render for desktop vs. mobile.

Any advice on getting the site to look good for both desktop and mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking into a framework if you are concerned with mobile compatibility. One of the more popular ones is [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

The way it works is by checking the browser size and adjusting the CSS accordingly so that the page still renders well for mobile and desktop.